# Spring Boot Starter. How to stop from initialization other starters before starter 'x' finish beans creation?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I found [postgresql-embedded](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/postgresql-embedded) and write a *spring-boot-starter* for tests porpoises based on this project. After adding starter dependency  in project on run it fails with next error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "user"

**application.properties**

```
embedded.postgres.database-name=test
embedded.postgres.username=user
embedded.postgres.password=user
embedded.postgres.port=5433

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=user
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
```

Reason is that `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` runs before my starter that startup an embedded PostgreSQL. It is possible to set priority for starter or any other ways ?

**Starter sources:** https://github.com/esempla/spring-boot-starter-embedded-postgres

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up a dependency on your bean that starts Postgres from the `DataSource` bean. You can do so with a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` in your starter. You might like to take inspiration from Boot's own [`AbstractDependsOnBeanFactoryPostProcessor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/AbstractDependsOnBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java), its concrete subclasses such as [`MongoClientDependsOnBeanFactoryPostProcessor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoClientDependsOnBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java), and how it's [used in auto-configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/embedded/EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.java#L212-L225).

Comment: Thanks for advice. But in my case if I correctly understand there  dependencies should be set for `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` which is totally reverse from examples shown upper.  I have to init Postgres and then datasoure. I try to annotate auto configuration class with `@AutoConfigureBefore(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)` but nothing happens. Do you have some ideas?

Comment: The auto-configuration doesn't really matter and `@AutoConfigureBefore` won't help as it just control the order in which the configuration is processed and has no effect on the order in which any declared beans are created. What does matter is the `DataSource` bean that DataSourceAutoConfiguration` may have created. You need to configure its `BeanDefinition` so that it depends on your bean that starts embedded Postgres. As I tried to describe above, a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` is the way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot Autoconfiguration is working as it supposed to be as it assumes the Postgresql is already running when the datasource is being auto configured. Since this is a Special Case where you are using an Embedded Postgresql that starts from within the same application context, you will not be able to use Datasource Auto Configuration.

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter({PostgresAutoConfiguration.class})
public class CustomDataSourceConfiguration {

    @Value("${datasource.url}")
    private String dataSourceUrl;

    @Value("${datasource.driver-class}")
    private String dataSourceDriverClass;

    @Value("${datasource.username}")
    private String dataSourceUsername;

    @Value("${datasource.password}")
    private String dataSourcePassword;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
         // Logic to create the DataSource
    }


}
```

The `@AutoConfigureAfter` will make sure that the embedded Postgresql is loaded before the datasource is created.

Answer (score 0):

Already done thanks [Andy Wilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson) for advises. Problem was solved by creating creating **DependsOnBeanFactoryPostProcessor** as follow:

```
@Order
public class DataSourceDependsOnBeanFactoryPostProcessor extends AbstractDependsOnBeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    public DataSourceDependsOnBeanFactoryPostProcessor(String... dependsOn) {
        super(DataSource.class, LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.class, dependsOn);
    }
}
```

And adding this class as a configuration in AutoConfiguration class

```
@Configuration
protected static class EmbeddedPostgresDependencyConfiguration extends DataSourceDependsOnBeanFactoryPostProcessor{
    public EmbeddedPostgresDependencyConfiguration(){
        super("embeddedPostgres");
    }
}
```

Now this starter works fine for my test cases. Sources can by find there:
https://github.com/esempla/spring-boot-starter-embedded-postgres